# Apache Shiro Multirealm Authentication + find out which realm did the authentication

Tags: shiro

I have 2 possible realms to authenticate my users in my webapplication.

here are a few lines from my shiro.ini:

```
securityManager.realms = $ldapRealm, $saltedJdbcRealm
strategy = org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.FirstSuccessfulStrategy
securityManager.authenticator.authenticationStrategy = $strategy
```

Authentication works fine for both realms and the FirstSuccessfulStrategy works fine as well.

In my custom AuthenticationFilter within the `executeLogin()` method I have this code to do the login:

```
Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken(username, password);
currentUser.login(token);
```

How can I now determine which realm was resposible for the authentication after the .login() method is executed?

If the user was authenticated via the LDAP Realm I would like to get some more information about the user from the LDAP.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

```
Subject subj = SecurityUtils.getSubject()
SimplePrincipalCollection spc = (SimplePrincipalCollection) subj.getPrincipals();
Set<String> realmNames = spc.getRealmNames();
```

The `realmNames` variable should contain one element, the realm that authenticated the user.

If your realm implementation is a standard one then the `SimpleAuthenticationInfo` created when the user is authenticated will have been created with the name of the realm that successfully authenticated the user.